# moderncv themes

Tags: moderncv

Are there any available themes for `moderncv` other than *classic* and *casual*?

I googled it but no luck.

Comment: Note that with newer `moderncv` versions the themes files are named differently and you will have to rename your custom theme files to the new naming scheme. I updated my answer in order to reflect this.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The current version of [`moderncv`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) (version 2.3.1 of Feb 21, 2022) has 5 styles (other than the dummy `empty` one):

- [`casual`](https://github.com/xdanaux/moderncv/blob/master/examples/template_casual_orange.pdf) (default),
- [`classic`](https://github.com/xdanaux/moderncv/blob/master/examples/template_classic_green.pdf),
- [`oldstyle`](https://github.com/xdanaux/moderncv/blob/master/examples/template_oldstyle_grey.pdf),
- [`banking`](https://github.com/xdanaux/moderncv/blob/master/examples/template_banking_red.pdf), and
- [`fancy`](https://github.com/xdanaux/moderncv/blob/master/examples/template_fancy_purple.pdf)

and 8 color schemes:

- `black`,
- `blue`,
- `burgundy`,
- `green`,
- `grey`,
- `orange`,
- `purple`, and
- `red`.

Answer (score 19):

The themes for `moderncv` are located in files named `moderncvstyle<name>.sty` which are loaded by `moderncv` as sub-packages. In earlier versions they were named `moderncvtheme<name>.sty` instead, but this got changed (which broke my documents until I figured it out). You must rename existing older custom themes to match the new name in order to be found.

There are only three of these files included with `moderncv`:

- moderncvstylecasual.sty
- moderncvstyleclassic.sty
- moderncvstyleempty.sty

The `empty` theme is only minimal and doesn't include a real theme. There are no other files on CTAN which this names nor could I find others with a Google search. There is a possibility to create own themes, but no one seems to have posted one online yet.

Comment: Hi Martin, I did with the banking style file that but it can't compile. Any ideas?

Answer (score 15):

There is also the `empty` theme. You can relatively easily create you own theme, though.

If you are not satisfied with the output of `moderncv`, I suggest using one of these: http://rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/

Comment: The RPI templates can make very elegant resumes, though they are a little bit harder to use for a LaTeX beginner like me four years ago.