# Write custom theme for moderncv

Tags: moderncv

There are some preconfigures themes in moderncv: [moderncv themes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14559/moderncv-themes)

But, I want to create a own theme for moderncv, so that it's unique and maybe a bit nicer and more beautiful to read.

Does somebody know how to write the new theme files and how to put them into my .tex file?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it's the best way to do it but here's how I did it:

I added these lines at the top of my main document:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncvMyTheme}

\moderncvstyle{classicMyTheme}
\moderncvcolor{blueMyTheme}
```

I copied and customized the [`moderncv.cls` class](https://github.com/moderncv/moderncv/blob/master/moderncv.cls), renamed it to `moderncvMyTheme.cls`, saved it inside my project, and replaced the following line:

```latex
\ProvidesClass{moderncvMyTheme}
```

I copied and customized one of the styles, here the [`moderncvstyleclassic.sty` style file](https://github.com/moderncv/moderncv/blob/master/moderncvstyleclassic.sty), renamed it to `moderncvstyleclassicMyTheme.sty`, saved it inside my project, and replaced the following lines:

```latex
\ProvidesPackage{moderncvstyleclassicMyTheme}
```

Finally I copied and customized one of the color style files, here the [`moderncvcolorblue.sty` style file](https://github.com/moderncv/moderncv/blob/master/moderncvcolorblue.sty), renamed it to `moderncvcolorblueMyTheme.sty`, saved it inside my project, and replaced the following lines:

```latex
\ProvidesPackage{moderncvcolorblueMyTheme}
```

Hope that helps!